# Jetty authentication architecture

Tags: java, jetty

The Jetty authentication architecture uses the following 4 interfaces:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.server.UserIdentity
org.eclipse.jetty.security.LoginService
org.eclipse.jetty.security.IdentityService
java.security.Principal
```

Could somebody explain how these 4 interfaces interact to eachother in the authentication flow.

Browsing through the code seems not very helpful because there are so many corner cases. I am just interesting in the main flow.

Comment: Tried the documentation yet?

Comment: On a high level the documentation is very verbose. But on a lower level, the only thing I find about the individual components is in the javadoc. Sure, the source code could be sufficient. But I was hoping that somebody who already has a deeper understanding of these topics could give me a head start. Note: I'm not asking how to configure it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question is hard to answer as its very open ended / vague.

I'll try the simple answer first.

First, the basics, what's provided by the JVM:

- [`java.security.Principal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html) - this is the Servlet spec object that holds the person / company / group (login name).
- [`javax.security.auth.Subject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/auth/Subject.html) - this holds related information about the Principal (see link to javadoc for list of things it can reveal)

Now the Jetty specifics:

- `org.eclipse.jetty.server.UserIdentity` - this represents the identification for the user. aka the `Principal` and `Subject` for the user (if principal is null, then the user is not authenticated).  This also includes some methods to help with `isUserInRole(String)` style logic.
- `org.eclipse.jetty.security.IdentityService` - this associates the `UserIdentity` with the scope / thread that is belongs to. (this is an advanced concept that some security implementations need to hook into to handle security properly.  Jetty only ships with a default behavior that merely creates and performs no such association for `UserIdentity`.  As its not needed for the security implementations that Jetty ships with).
- `org.eclipse.jetty.security.LoginService` - this is the API for security implementations to use to create/validate/destroy runtime `UserIdentity` objects from a `login()` and `logout()` style events.

Finally, how it ties together:

- A `org.eclipse.jetty.security.Authenticator` is responsible for the HTTP portion of the authentication piece, such as responding with `401 Unauthorized` and `403 Forbidden`.  It uses the `LoginService` to do its thing.
- The `LoginService` uses the `IdentityService` to associate the `UserIdentity` to the thread processing the request.
- The default Servlet behavior exposes the `Principal` directly, via [`HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal()).
- The `Subject` is not available via the standard Servlet API.
- The `UserIdentity` is partially exposed via the [`HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole(String role)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#isUserInRole(java.lang.String)) method.
- The `LoginService` is not accessible via the Servlet API directly, but you can use the [`HttpServletRequest.login(String user, String pass)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and [`HttpServletRequest.logout()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#logout()) respectively to access these essential features.
- There are also some authentication and authorization features of the Servlet spec that are auto wired:

  - Any `<security-constraint>` sections in the `WEB-INF/web.xml`
  - Use of [`javax.annotation.security`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/security/package-summary.html) annotations:

    - [`@DeclareRoles`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/security/DeclareRoles.html)
    - [`@DenyAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/security/DenyAll.html)
    - [`@PermitAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/security/PermitAll.html)
    - [`@RolesAllowed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/security/RolesAllowed.html)
    - [`@RunAs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/security/RunAs.html)